# Function to assign variables to range

Tags: excel, vba

I tried something like the code below.

```vb
Public currentplayer as range
Public opponentplayer as range

Set currentplayer = Cells.Find("CURRENTPLAYER", , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
Set opponentplayer = Cells.Find("OPPONENTPLAYER", , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
```

However, as more ranges get defined it becomes messier and tedious.

I tried to come up with something as follows:

```vb
Public variablename As Range

Function assigntovar(variablename, lookfor)
    Set variablename = Cells.Find(lookfor, , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
End Function

Sub definevariables()
    Call assigntovar("currentplayer", "CURRENTPLAYER")
    Call assigntovar("opponentplayer", "OPPONENTPLAYER")
End Sub
```

Are there ways or methods that can be done or would I have to go with the original way?

Comment: Could you share the whole initial code so we can understand what you're trying to do (the 'big picture') and share ideas on how to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the result of the function to reuse it (I renamed the function!)

```vb
Function getFieldForLabel(ws As Worksheet, label As String) As Range
    On Error Resume Next    'in case label not found
    Set getFieldForLabel = ws.Cells.Find(label, , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
End Function
```

And then call it like this

```vb
Sub definevariables()
    
    Dim currentplayer As Range
    Set currentplayer = getFieldForLabel(ActiveSheet, "CURRENTPLAYER")
    
    Dim opponentplayer As Range
    Set opponentplayer = getFieldForLabel(ActiveSheet, "OPPONENTPLAYER")
    
End Sub
```

As you can see `ActiveSheet` is passed as well to the function. Just to be *explicit* on which sheet label should be searched. You can use sheetname as well like eg `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Your sheetname")`

Comment: ahhs thankyouu for your reply! so it seems like i cannot avoid the dimming of variables as range?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you expected something like this:

```
Function assigntovar(variablename, lookfor)
   Dim found As Range
   On Error Resume Next
    Set found = Cells.Find(lookfor, , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not found Is Nothing Then _
         Names.Add variablename, found
End Function

Sub definevariables()
    Call assigntovar("currentplayer", "CURRENTPLAYER")
    Call assigntovar("opponentplayer", "OPPONENTPLAYER")
    MsgBox Range("currentplayer").Address
    MsgBox Range("opponentplayer").Address
End Sub
```

This code creates workbook names that are visible in the Name Manager.
You can access them in VBA as `Range("name")`